# find the correct algorithme to find all the possible binary combination

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write a non-recursive Java method called `showStar`, which takes a string, and generates ALL possible combinations of that string without the mask “*” characters.

```
receiving this as an input "1011*00*10", 
the method `showStar` will display output like:
1011000010
1011000110
1011100010
1011100110
```

I tried this way, however, as soon as the number of possible cases is more than the String length, the output is not exact.

Here is my code.

```
public static void showStar(String s){
        String save;
        int count = 0;
        int poss;

        save = s.replace('*','0');
        StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder(save);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '*' && myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                myString.setCharAt(i, '1');
                System.out.println(myString);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '*' && myString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                myString.setCharAt(i, '0');
                System.out.println(myString);
            }
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Say there are k *s. Then there are 2^k solutions. You can generate these by copying the bits from the integers 0 - 2^k-1 in order. (adding sufficient leading zeroes)

E.g. 1**1:

```
0 = 00 => 1001
1 = 01 => 1011
2 = 10 => 1101
3 = 11 => 1111
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
if  I have 001*100*1 I understand your algorithm, however quick question, in what way can I locate and change all the "*" to the right output. For example, in my code, I was looping on the String to find and change them. how can I implement yours?

Comment: Alex added an implementation of my solution in the non-recursive section of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here a recursive algoritm works just perfectly:

1. You check if an input string contains an asterisk '*' by using an `x = str.indexOf('*');`
2. If no asterisk is present `(x == -1)`, you just print the string and return
3. Otherwise, you replace the asterisk at the position to '0' and '1' and call `showStar()` recursively for both replacements

```java
public static void showStar(String str) {
    int x = str.indexOf('*');
    if(x == -1) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    String prefix = str.substring(0, x);
    String suffix = str.substring(x + 1);
    for (char i = '0'; i <= '1'; i++) {
        showStar(prefix + i + suffix);
    }
}
```

**Update**
In non-recursive implementation we need to collect the asterisk positions, then prepare a binary representation and set appropriate bits at the known positions:

```java
public static void showStar(String str) {
    int[] xs = IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                        .filter(i -> str.charAt(i) == '*')
                        .toArray();
    int num = (int) Math.pow(2, xs.length); // 2^n variants for n asterisks
    String format = xs.length > 0 ? "%" + xs.length + "s" : "%s"; // fix if no '*'

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        String bin = String.format(format, Integer.toBinaryString(i))
                           .replace(' ', '0');  // pad leading zeros
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

        // set 0 or 1 in place of asterisk(s)
        for (int j = 0; j < xs.length; j++) {
            sb.setCharAt(xs[j], bin.charAt(j));
        }
            
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```